# How to use forward declaration with inherited files

Tags: c++, inheritance, forward-declaration

I am having quite the issue with forward declarations. I have a class, `SharedContext.h` that has, among other things, a pointer to another class `StateMachine.h`. StateMachine also has a pointer to the SharedContext. This would be easy enough if that was all. I have other classes like this already. I would just need to:

`#include "StateMachine.h"` in my `SharedContext.h` file, and forward declare the SharedContext in the `StateMachine.h` file, then `#include "SharedContext.h"` in the `StateMachine.cpp` file.

This breaks down however, when I need to include more classes into `StateMachine`. I have a `State_Base.h`, and a `State_DIYACMenu.h` and `State_DIYACMenu.cpp`. `State_Base.h` also has a pointer to `SharedContext`, and needs to include it. `State_DIYACMenu.h` obviously includes `State_Base.h`, and then finally my `StateMachine` includes the `State_DIYACMenu`. So there is the circular dependency.

I thought I would then be able to solve this by using a forward declaration of SharedContext in `State_Base.h`, then using `#include "SharedContext.h"` in the `State_DIYACMenu.cpp` and `StateMachine.cpp`. But I am still getting a "Member access into incomplete type StateMachine" error in the StateMachine class.

Link to the github project: https://github.com/djpeach/DIY-Arcade-Cabinet/tree/master/menu/menu

Comment: Seems confusing with no minimal class examples or file examples. One thing I suggest would be to make sure you also have header guards. Either #pragma once or #ifndef SOMETHING_H #define SOMETHING_H #endif

Comment: yes I am using #pragma once in all header files. I triple checked this. And its more than a bit of code, so I will add a link to github. one moment

Comment: I recommend placing the code, in [mcve] form, in the question rather than linking to it. Links rot and when this one goes, the question becomes pretty much useless.

Comment: ok, i'll get that written up. in the meantime, have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a walk around and avoid using forward declarations.

Forward declarations are a nice method to resolve circular dependency when you write simple enough code but when your code grows in complexity it becomes harder and harder to code without getting into a circular dependency issue due to various restrictions it implies.

To get around it - use interface classes.

```
class My_Interface_Of_StateMachine
{
public:
    virtual ~My_Interface_Of_StateMachine() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
// declarations of all functions you use
};
// put it into a header My_Interface_Of_StateMachine.h
```

Let your `SharedContext` have only pointer towards an `My_Interface_Of_StateMachine` and make your `StateMachine` inherit from the interface class `My_Interface_Of_StateMachine`.

```
class StateMachine:
    public My_Interface_Of_StateMachine
{
public:
    void foo() override;
//implementation of all the functions
};
```

This way you have no circular dependency.

If for some reason you find that using virtual methods is too slow then you can cast the interface class into the real class via dynamic casting in the cpp file.